# segfaults when compiling on newer version of glibc ( 2.3 -> 2.10 )

Tags: c, linux, glibc, openssh

I try to modify ssh session logging patch to sshd from kdvelectronics site.

Code hasn't changed much from openssh 4.x to 5.x , but now sshd segfaults when script_open function calls ( as gdb says )

```
Core was generated by `sshd: root [priv]        '.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f687910ae69 in vfprintf () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f687910ae69 in vfprintf () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f68791a98c2 in __fprintf_chk () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x000000000044ed03 in script_open ()
#3  0x000000000040ad2c in main ()
```

The code that crashes is:

```
strftime(logname, sizeof(logname), "%F.%T", gmtime(&tvec));
```

or

```
snprintf(fname, sizeof(fname), "%s/openssh.%s.%08x.typescript", SCRIPTDIR, username, rnd);
```

Full script.c listing is here http://pastebin.com/48B39K8s , I've commented line 50 and removed logname variable from line 53 .

I just wanna know, what changed in glibc since 2.3 that these functions cause segfault or where to read about it.

Comment: Segfaulting inside glibc doesn't mean that it's glibc's fault. If you pass in an invalid pointer/string, bad things can happen.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, seems that something changed, but it's difficult to find because glibc changelog is huge to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turned out to be pretty simple. I've changed mentioned strings to

```
strftime(logname, FILENAME_MAX+1, "%F.%T", gmtime(&tvec));
```

```
snprintf(fname, FILENAME_MAX+1, "%s/openssh.%s.%08x.typescript", SCRIPTDIR, username, rnd);
```

Ofc it's dirty, but works.

Comment: I do not think that substituting FILENAME_MAX+1 for sizeof(logname) should make any difference. You can verify that those values will be the same given the way you've declared logname. I suspect that simply un-commenting-out the line 50 strftime() that loaded logname was the actual fix, not the change to FILENAME_MAX+1.

Comment: I've returned it back, removed all my comment signs and changed sizeof(...) to their respective FILENAME_MAX+1 defines. Yeah, their values shall be identical, but somehow FILENAME_MAX+1 makes a difference and now sshd works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the reason your code crashes is that (with line 50 commented out) you have left `logname` with undefined contents when you use it at line 60.  You mentioned that you removed the `logname` reference from line 53 along with commenting out line 50 -- perhaps you just forgot to also remove it from line 60 in that case?